# How can I tell which namespace agiven class belongs to?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, namespaces

It happens a lot that I might find a snippet of code on the web that I want to use, but the snippet doesn't provide the necessary imports I need ("Using" in C#), so I am left with another search task of trying to figure out what namespace a class/variable type belongs to.  This problem is only happeneing to me when I program Android with Xamarin in Visual Studio C#, because I cannot see where the android documentation shows me this info. (If I am programming in normal C# then the MSDN Documentation is very clear what namespace each class belongs to.)

Here is an example.  I found the following code I want to use:

```
Configuration configuration = yourActivity.getResources().getConfiguration();
int screenWidthDp = configuration.screenWidthDp; //The current width of the available screen space, in dp units, corresponding to screen width resource qualifier.
int smallestScreenWidthDp = configuration.smallestScreenWidthDp; //The smallest screen size an application will see in normal operation, corresponding to smallest screen width resource qualifier.
```

And the answerer even gave a link to the Android Documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#screenWidthDp

However within VS I get an error message:  "The type or namespace name 'Configuration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Well, yes I am missing a using directive, but what is a way of figuring out the name of the namespace I am missing?  Again if it is a normal .Net class I have no trouble, this only happens to me with Android classes within Xamarin/VS, because I am not finding what I need in the Android documentation.  Could someone point me to it, please?

Comment: Auto-import it? It'll show you a list if there are multiple, and there aren't many to pick from when the return type is fixed

Comment: google "xamarin api android configuration", first hit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, I press F1 on a class to find the online document of it. Try it out on the Android class

You can also find your desired documentation in the [Xamarin page](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Content.Res.Configuration/#memberlist) of Microsoft.
You can also search this page for any other class that you might need in the future.

Comment: Thanks, the secret was to go to the Xamarin page of Microsoft instead of the Android documentation.  The issue I was having is that Xamarin implements some getXXXX() Methods as properties.  So the working code is:

Comment: `  using Android.Content.Res;     Configuration configuration = this.Resources.Configuration;     int screenWidthDp = configuration.ScreenWidthDp;      int smallestScreenWidthDp = configuration.SmallestScreenWidthDp;   `

Comment: right, most Android get/set methods are translated into more C# friendly Properties.  This is documented on the Xamarin Android API pages