# Android.OS.Environment... which namespace?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, io

I want to save some data to the storage (internal/external) of an Anroid device. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36545008/xamarin-android-save-text-file) where they got the external storage path with the following line:

`var sdCardPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path;`

Seems fair. But my Visual Studio says the following:

> The name 'Android' does not exist in the current context

So I've been wondering in which namespace does this `Android` reside? I tried quite a lot (e.g. AutoImport, but that seems to give me the wrong parent; or pressing F1 for documentation like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47460557/how-can-i-tell-which-namespace-agiven-class-belongs-to)) but didnt figure out how to get this to work. Which NuGet- Package do I have to get to obtain this function. **Or am I doing something completely wrong?**

This is the namespace that AutoImport gives me:

`Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path;`

but then it tells me that Android has no `OS` member. And upon checking, I found that `Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android` has no members at all, so theres nothing beneath it. Is my `Xamarin.Forms` depricated? According to my NuGet- Packagemanager, everything is up to date.

These are the NuGet- Packages my project uses:

1. `Xamarin.Essentials`
2. `Xamarin.Forms`
3. `OxyPlot.Core`
4. `OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows

Comment: @Jason I expected you.
Jokes aside: Thank you. Turns out its depricated. Shall I delete this question or you post an answer that I mark as accepted answer?

Comment: Can you not use ‘string filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData); var fileName=Path.Combine(filePath,"***.***");’?

Comment: @Saamer I can. I didn't know that it is possible and thought it would be best to do it like the post I linked suggested. But Jason helped me understanding that it's easier to use the solution you also mentioned.

Comment: `var sdCardPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path` works on native android project .Which project are you using this code?

Comment: I use it on a general project for all platforms. (Android, iOS, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just typing the answer here so we can close this question...

The problem with what you are trying to do is that you need to understand that there is a separation of concerns/abstraction. The Core project is referenced by the Android & iOS projects, but the Android & iOS projects are not referenced by the Core project. Schematically,

`Core-->Android & Core-->iOS` but 
`Core<-x-Android, Core<-x-iOS`

This is by design, and even though you can make it do what you are trying, you shouldn't.

We know that the iOS & Android SDKs are very different. So in order to get the path/file name, you have to perform different functions underneath. And the code that you shared is the correct way of retrieving the path/file name natively ONLY for Android.

In order to make it work for both iOS & Android, Xamarin Forms provides us with an abstraction layer that takes care of everything underneath for us, and allows us to use this:

```
string filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData); 
var fileName=Path.Combine(filePath,".");
```

There's also many other ways of doing this as shown in the official [Microsoft docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows).